# Why doesn't the plyr package use my parallel backend?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr

I'm trying to use the `parallel` package in R for parallel operations rather than `doSNOW` since it's built-in and ostensibly the way the R Project wants things to go. I'm doing something wrong that I can't pin down though. Take for example this:

```
a <- rnorm(50)
b <- rnorm(50)

arr <- matrix(cbind(a,b),nrow=50)

aaply(arr,.margin=1,function(x){x[1]+x[2]},.parallel=F)
```

This works just fine, producing the sums of my two columns. But if I try to bring in the parallel package:

```
library(parallel)
nodes <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(nodes)
setDefaultCluster(cl)

aaply(arr,.margin=1,function(x){x[1]+x[2]},.parallel=T)
```

It throws the error

```
2: In setup_parallel() : No parallel backend registered
3: executing %dopar% sequentially: no parallel backend registered
```

Am I initializing the backend wrong?

Comment: For anyone looking at this post, I've long since abandoned parallel in favor of doParallel, which seems to Just Work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this setup:

```
library(doParallel)
library(plyr)

nodes <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(nodes)
registerDoParallel(cl)

aaply(ozone, 1, mean,.parallel=TRUE)

stopCluster(cl)
```

Since I have never used `plyr` for parallel computing I have no idea why this issues warnings. The result is correct anyway.

Answer (score -2):

The documentation for `aaply` states

> .parallel: if ‘TRUE’, apply function in parallel, using parallel
>             backend provided by foreach

so presumably you need to use the `foreach` package rather than the `parallel` package.