# llply, alply etc running serial in Windows

Tags: r, plyr

I'm finding plyr methods running in serial instead of parallel in Windows - the example below is typical, the cluster is created and works but on execution of the llply statement I observe brief CPU activity and increased memory use on all the cluster node processes, but then they all cease to process anything and the rsession process continues using ~100% of its processor until it returns (correct) results.

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterExport(cl, "str_replace")
mydata$textfield <- unlist(llply(mydata$textfield, function(x) str_replace(x, "  ", " "),.parallel = T))
```

By comparison, if I use parLapply instead on the same cluster I immediately see all the cluster node processes start using ~100% CPU, and the results return quickly:

```
mydata$textfield <- unlist(parLapply(cl, mydata$textfield, function(x) str_replace(x, "  ", " ")))
```

I'm using `R 3.2.5` with `plyr 1.8.4`

Thanks for any hints as to why this is happening - I've observed it with various statements and I can't identify anything in common between them that differentiates from the circumstances where plyr is succeeding in processing in parallel - yes, it works in some of my code but not all...

Comment: Are you using the Package ‘doParallel’?

Comment: Yes, and it seems to work in some cases but not this one

Comment: Not sure how applicable the accepted solution is but did you take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642722/why-doesnt-the-plyr-package-use-my-parallel-backend

Comment: Is it possible to put together a working example for people to test? Also why use llply when parLapply seems to work?  I know there must be some reason for preferring one over the other.